# Jquery this inside jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access method2 from within my each function. I'm getting the following error. How do I get this to work?

> ReferenceError: method2 is not defined

```
method1: function() {
    $('tr[data-quantity]').each(function(value) {
        this.method2(value);
    })
},

method2: function(value) {
    console.log('test')
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `method1` and `method2` belong to the same object with definition like this:

```
var obj = {
   method1: function(){},
   method2: function(){}
};
```

You can try:

```
    method1: function() {
        var self = this;
        $('tr[data-quantity]').each(function(value) {
            self.method2(value);
        })
    },

    method2: function(value) {
        console.log('test')
    },
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I assumed it was known since I included the commas, anyhow it worked perfectly, what causes this to happen? Is it losing it's object reference do to the jquery each function?

Comment: @Code Junkie: `this` in javascript changes based on context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . In your case, the context has changed when it enters the `jquery.each` which is the current item of the current iteration.